# Unable to run react application in nodejs 16.15.0v,npm 9.6.7v and python3

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules, npm-install

My application runs fine on Nodejs 14.15.4v and npm 8.5.4v but when upgrading to Nodejs 16.15.0v ,npm 9.6.7v I'm facing a lot of issues.

My json file

```
{
  "private": true,
  "name": "gb-tools",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "GB Tools",
}
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "concurrently": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.7.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.19.1",
    "https-proxy-agent": "^2.2.1",
    "jest": "^21.2.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.3",
    "node-sass":"^6.0.1",
    "sass-loader": "^11.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.0",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^5.0.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.4.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.1.1"
  }
```

When I run npm install --force following is the error:

```
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: gb-tools@1.0.0
npm WARN Found: webpack@4.46.0
npm WARN node_modules/webpack
npm WARN   peer webpack@"^5.0.0" from sass-loader@11.1.1    
npm WARN   node_modules/sass-loader
npm WARN     dev sass-loader@"^11.1.1" from the root project
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer webpack@"^4.0.0" from css-loader@2.1.1        
npm WARN node_modules/css-loader
npm WARN   dev css-loader@"^2.0.0" from the root project    
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: gb-tools@1.0.0
npm WARN Found: webpack@4.46.0
npm WARN node_modules/webpack
npm WARN   peer webpack@"^5.0.0" from sass-loader@11.1.1    
npm WARN   node_modules/sass-loader
npm WARN     dev sass-loader@"^11.1.1" from the root project
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer webpack@"^4.0.0" from file-loader@3.0.1       
npm WARN node_modules/file-loader
npm WARN   dev file-loader@"^3.0.0" from the root project   
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: gb-tools@1.0.0
npm WARN Found: webpack@4.46.0
npm WARN node_modules/webpack
npm WARN   peer webpack@"^5.0.0" from sass-loader@11.1.1
npm WARN   node_modules/sass-loader
npm WARN     dev sass-loader@"^11.1.1" from the root project
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer webpack@"^1.0.0 || ^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0" from html-webpack-plugin@3.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/html-webpack-plugin
npm WARN   dev html-webpack-plugin@"^3.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: gb-tools@1.0.0
npm WARN Found: webpack@4.46.0
npm WARN node_modules/webpack
npm WARN   peer webpack@"^5.0.0" from sass-loader@11.1.1
npm WARN   node_modules/sass-loader
npm WARN     dev sass-loader@"^11.1.1" from the root project
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer webpack@"^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0" from url-loader@1.1.2
npm WARN node_modules/url-loader
npm WARN   dev url-loader@"^1.0.1" from the root project

npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.1.2: The v1 package contains DANGEROUS / INSECURE binaries. Upgrade to safe fsevents v2
npm WARN deprecated sw-precache@5.2.1: Please migrate to Workbox: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/migrations/migrate-from-sw
npm WARN deprecated extract-text-webpack-plugin@3.0.2: Deprecated. Please use https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: The v1 package contains DANGEROUS / INSECURE binaries. Upgrade to safe fsevents v2
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: The v1 package contains DANGEROUS / INSECURE binaries. Upgrade to safe fsevents v2        
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: The v1 package contains DANGEROUS / INSECURE binaries. Upgrade to safe fsevents v2        
npm WARN deprecated sw-toolbox@3.6.0: Please migrate to Workbox: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/migrations/migrate-from-sw
```

Application fails to run. I'm new to Reactjs. Can anyone please help me. I'm stuck with this for past 5 days.

Comment: If you are upgrading then you might have to change a few things, especially packages that are not supported in the new version. It is not recommended to switch versions in between a project unless you know exactly what you are doing. you have to go through all the packages you installed in modules.js and check if they are supported in new version.

Comment: @AniketPandey : We had to switch versions after migration and it became mandatory.Have shared package.json as part of the question.Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Have you manually changed the version inside of package.json? If so, don't do that. On your local machine, just uninstall all dependencies(packages) and install them one by one again with updated versions. That way you will automatically have all the right versions of sub-dependencies on which those packages depend. What is happening here is that some packages need specific versions of some other packages to work.

Comment: Just look at the warning and do what they tell you to. Migrate from deprecated packages to latest ones. Why don't you use the @latest flag while installing packages? Is there a reason why you are using some specific version?

Comment: Followed the below steps : 1) Deleted node_modules and package-lock.json 2) Ran npm update --save. 3) installed all dependencies using npm install --force 4) Getting error like 'Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js)'.Can you please suggest what to do for this. Using node-sass 6.0.1 nd sass-loader 7.3.1..

Comment: Now run `npm uninstall sass sass-loader` and then `npm I sass@latest sass-loader@latest`

Comment: And don't use `node-sass`, use `sass` instead. I think node-sass is deprecated. Check documentation for it.

Comment: Thank you...Application is working fine with latest node version..